# Why am I getting zero from mov ax, bx+si+1?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
    mov     ax,10
    mov     bx,4
    mov     si,ax
    mov     ax,bx+si+1
    LEA     ax,[bx+si+1]
```

When I add bx,si and 1 together and move to ax , the result is 0.
At the next line, when I use LEA it works and I get 15.

Why am I getting zero when using move?

Comment: really unclear what you're trying to do here, what's the purpose of the code?

Comment: The purpose of the code is to make ax hold the value '15'. (the given registers are ax=10 and bx=4)

Comment: I'm curious: which assembler let you write an absurdity like `mov     ax,bx+si+1`?

Comment: Does emu8086 assemble `mov   ax, bx+si+1` to load instruction or something?  It's not valid syntax for any normal x86 assembler, so we can only guess.  But if it does assemble to `mov ax, [bx+si+1]`, and memory address `[ds:15]` contains two bytes of zeros, that would explain it.  Oh, you just said 8086, not emu8086.  So what assembler is this??

Comment: Probably get rid of that assembler :) ... use rather something with stricter syntax checks (nasm?), if you can. Although each x86 assembler has a bit different syntax for some things, if you are following some lessons/tutorial, it may later require to adjust the source.

Comment: @Keddy1201 the purpose of that code is to demonstrate that `ax` becomes `0` when not expected. I find this ALMOST proper [mcve] (except missing description of target platform and assembler used).

Comment: Would you post the data segment, I need to see you variables' content.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I would recommend the following steps. (1) Run `mov ax,bx+si+1` through your assembler; inspect the binary code that gets generated. (2) Do the same for `mov ax,[bx+si+1]`. (3) Compare the two byte streams. I would not be surprised if both statements would generate the same code.

Comment: @Ped7g Yes, I use emu8086. I asked because I came across this code without the 4th line (the weird one), and I was wondering if it'll work in another way (the 4th line that I added) , which it didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is : "Why am I getting zero from mov ax, bx+si+1?". It's hard to give you an accurate answer because you forgot to tell what compiler you are using and your code snippet doesn't include the data segment so we can't see your data. What we can do is to test your code with some numbers in the data segment and see the results :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data    
xy db 0A0h,0A1h,0A2h,0A3h,0A4h,0A5h,0A6h,0A7h,0A8h,0A9h,0AAh,0ABh,0ACh,0ADh,0AEh,0AFh,0B0h
.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  ax, 10
  mov  bx, 4
  mov  si, ax
  mov  ax, bx+si+1       ;◄■■ #1 (EXPLANATION BELOW ▼)
  LEA  ax, [bx+si+1]     ;◄■■ #2 (EXPLANATION BELOW ▼)
```

Let's illustrate what happens here:

[image]

This is what is going on:

**#1** Because of the presence of a base register (`bx`) and an index register (`si`) the sum is interpreted as a memory addressing, so the code gets the data in memory location 15. `ax` register size is 2 bytes, so the result is that `ax` gets 2 bytes starting at memory location 15, in our data segment those 2 bytes are `0AFh` and `0B0h`. `al` is the lower byte of `ax`, so the first byte (`0AFh`) stores there, the higher byte `ah` gets the second byte (`0B0h`), and this is how `ax` becomes `0B0AFh`.

**#2** We said that the presence of the base register `bx` and the index register `si` is interpreted as a memory addressing, so `[bx+si+1]` points to memory location 15 (`0AFh`). Instruction `lea` stands for `load effective address`, its purpose is to get an address from inside the data segment. Your line of code is getting the effective address of memory location 15 (`0AFh`), which is 15.

So much theory requires a demonstration, and here it is:

Next is a screenshot from EMU8086 : the **BLUE** arrow points to the original line of code, the **GREEN** arrow points to the line of code as it is been interpreted (as a memory addressing), and the **RED** arrow shows the effect in register `ax` (`B0AFh`).

[image]

Now the screenshot for the next instruction : the **BLUE** arrow points to the original line of code, the **GREEN** arrow points to the line of code as it is been interpreted (notice it's identical to the previous one), and the **RED** arrow shows the effect in register `ax` (`0Fh`).

[image]

Finally, let's test the code in Visual Studio 2013 : next screenshot proves that `mov ax, bx+si+1` is invalid, and the other line gives the same result as EMU8086 (`ax`=`0FH`) :

[image]

So, "why are you getting zero from mov ax, bx+si+1?" Because you probably have a zero in memory location 15 inside your data segment. You maybe thought that `bx+si+1` was going to give you a normal number, 15, but now you know that using base and index registers will be interpreted as memory addressing, **so you don't get the number 15 but the data inside memory location 15**.

Comment: So another reason why EMU8086 needs to be taken behind the barn and shot.

Comment: What is going on with this emulator?  Both `mov ax, bx+si+1` and `mov ax, [bx+si]+01h` are invalid instructions.  What is the byte output of the `mov` line?  You can only see the byte output for the `lea` and the following instruction in the screenshots

Answer (score 3):

Jose gave you detailed answer what is happening in your code, you certainly should try to replicate his results with your emu8086, so you are capable to debug your code alone.

I want just to add a "high-level" answer.

You probably sort of missed what assembler is. It's not regular programming language, but more like aliases for actual machine code of target CPU.

That means that any instruction you write is almost always mapped 1:1 to the actual CPU instruction (some assemblers support so called "pseudo instruction", which are compiled into few real instructions by well defined rules - this is very uncommon on x86, and I'm not aware of such pseudo instruction in emu8086).

And instruction `mov register, some_math_expression` doesn't exist, the source value must be single number (either immediate value encoded in the opcode, or other register, or value fetched from computer memory (your case)).

The confusing part is, that x86 does support very complex memory addressing modes, in the 32b mode for example `[eax+eax*4+imm32]` is valid (imm32 = 32b immediate value encoded directly in the instruction, that's where the address "count" is stored, but in 16b mode it's only 16b number). In 16b mode the legal combinations of values and registers for [addressing are very limited](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH04/CH04-2.html#HEADING2-23), but they still may look as mathematical expression on first sight.

But they are not. It's hard-coded in instruction opcode, so each of the legal combinations has it's own binary number, the CPU doesn't read that as "some bx register plus some di register plus some number", it reads the second byte value of opcode (in binary it will be `10000001` I think, too lazy to verify), and the transistors on the chip are designed for that value to work as `[bx+di+displacement]` addressing mode.

For example for the `inc byte ptr [bx+di+imm16]` (`mov` is simpler, just loads the value):

CPU reads the instruction opcode `0xFF` = `inc`, then it reads the addressing mode `0x81` (I think, didn't verify), so it knows it's "[bx+di+disp]", then it reads another two more bytes following, to get the 16b of displacement value, and finally adds those values together to get 16b offset into memory.

Then it takes the segment value (`ds` by default for this instruction, unless segment prefix opcode was used to override it for following single instruction) and adds it to the offset to produce the 20b physical address into memory chip (see any documentation of real mode addressing to learn how segment+offset are combined and why I'm talking about 20b and not 32b).

This 20b value is then set on the pins of CPU connected to memory chip (by "bus" = lot of "wires" or paths on PCB, on old 8086: 20 for addressing, 16 for data and some more for read/write/status handling) and memory chip is instructed to load value from the address which is read on the bus (I'm talking about simple "8086" computer, ignoring all the heavy caching mechanisms being present in modern PC, where CPU doesn't talk to memory chips directly any more).

After some time the memory chip will manage to switch it's internal state in such way, that the pins on the "data" side of bus are set like the value in memory cell at that address, so CPU can now "read" those pins and store that into temporary unnamed register. Then it runs the increment process over it, and sets the data bus pins to the new value (address part of bus very likely holds the same address whole time), and instructs memory chip to write the value.

And that's how the value in memory at address "bx+di+displacement" turns (for example) from 6 to 7.

... where I was...

Oh, so it's not free mathematical expression, but one of the legal addressing modes, hard-wired in the CPU.

emu8086 unfortunately doesn't yell at you for the missing `[]`, instead it will silently produce the only possible instruction which looks similar to what you wrote.

BTW, this should make it easy for you to understand the `LEA` instruction and why the original syntax is using `[]`, so it looks like it will access memory.

`lea` is the `mov` instruction with removed guts, so after the address calculation of the memory cell to "mov" it stops, doesn't contact memory chip at all, but fills the destination register with the 16b memory offset value which was calculated in the first phase of processing.

Comment: Addendum for completeness ... any real universal mathematical expression has to be broken down into simple-enough steps, which can be done by CPU instructions, like `add / sub / mul / div / shr / xor / ...`. But sometimes the complex addressing "math" together with `lea` can be used to calculate some special math expressions, my example of 32b `lea eax,[eax+eax*4+disp]` is fast version of `eax = 5 * eax + constant;`. This can be done only with expressions which can be somehow "bend" to fit into the rules of one of x86 memory addressing modes. Sort of "trick".