# Assembly Language 8086 - Can't add relative quantities

Tags: assembly

I've just started studying assembly a few months ago and I would like a bit of help with an assignment I've got for Uni.

The problem statement is:

```
Being given a string of bytes, sort it ascending
```

My code is:

```
assume cs:code,ds:data

data segment
    S1 db 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4 ;given string
    L1 EQU $-S1
    index1 db 0
    index2 db 0
    cont db 0
data ends


code segment
    start:

    mov AX,data
    mov DS,AX

    sort1:
        inc index1 
        sort2:
            inc index2
            cmps S1[index1],S2[index2]
            jg switch
            jng fin1 
            switch:
                mov S1[index1],AL
                mov S1[index2],AH
                mov S1[index1],AH
                mov S1[index2],AL
            fin1:
                cmp index2,L1
                JL sort2
                JNL sort1

    mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h 
code ends
end start
```

The problem is that, when I compile it with **Turbo Debugger**, it prompts the error 'Can't add relative quantities' (on lines 22,28,32,33,34,35 to be precise)

Why is this error prompted and how can I solve the issue, thanks!

---

Comment: Several times there you're trying to use a form of addressing that does not exist. Reading a value from memory as part of an address calculation is not even close to what's possible.

Comment: *"few months ago"* .. more like *"just"* started. Anyway, so start, read some theory first, then try programming again. At the current level you can't program in asm, just guess, and if you are any good at combinatorics, you can easily calculate how many possibilities there are to fill for example 100 bytes with random instructions, the chance that it will work as you want is zero. How do you compile it with turbo debugger? I know how it can compile single instruction when you overwrite some code in debugger, but never seen it compiling whole source, for that Turbo Assembler was used.

Comment: IMO this recent question and answers there can give you some insight, where to focus: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40719027/4271923 (it's not duplicate, but the answers may fill up many gaps you have now).

Comment: `cmps S1[index1],S2[index2]` e.g. : That's 4 accesses to memory, that's a bit more than the CPU is able to. Adressing modes are limited in Assembler, load the stuff into registers

Comment: BTW you should reset `index2` (from `index1`) at the start of the inner loop, just before `sort2:`. And, `inc index1` is at the wrong end of the outer loop - you'll skip element 0.

Answer (score 0):

On solution to your problem is to use index registers `SI` and `DI` instead of variables, example (copy-paste it to test it) :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    S1 db 3, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 4, 5 ;given string
    L1 EQU $-S1
.code
    start:

    mov AX,@data
    mov DS,AX

    mov si, offset S1        ;◄■■ INSTEAD OF INDEX1.
    sort1:
        mov  di, si          ;◄■■ INSTEAD OF INDEX2.            
        inc  di              ;◄■■ DI = SI+1.
        sort2:  
            mov  AL, [si]
            mov  AH, [di]
            cmp  AL, AH
            jng  fin1       
            switch:
                mov [si],AH
                mov [di],AL
            fin1:    
            inc di
            cmp di, L1       ;◄■■ LAST ITEM.
            jbe sort2        ;◄■■ IF DI <= LAST ITEM
        inc si
        cmp si, l1-1         ;◄■■ LAST-1 ITEM.
        jbe sort1            ;◄■■ IF SI <= LAST-1 ITEM

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h 
code ends
end start
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have removed `L1 EQU $-S1` and hard coded the length. Also it's strange the way you have `jg switch; jmp fin1; switch:` when `jng fin1` will do.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I saw it more as a suggestion than a final solution, but your recomendations are valid so they have been applied (thanks).